# Is there any way so that my angular app can connect to scanner?

Tags: angularjs

I want my angular app to detect scanner and perform scanning functionalities? how will i get this functionality in my app?

Answer (score 0):

That depends on the type of scanner you are using.

Most scanners connected to a network have an IP. You can login to the scanner at that IP to configure it. But they may not expose an API to send/receive instructions.

Browsers are not designed to connect with scanners. If you want to achieve this through the browser, you will need a server in the middle to receive instructions from client and pass them on to the scanner.